# How to extract words with exactly one vowel

Tags: r, regex

I have strings like these:

```
turns <- c("does him good to stir him up now and again .", 
           "when , when I see him he w's on the settees .",
           "yes it 's been eery for a long time .",
           "blissful timing , indeed it was ")
```

What I'm trying to do is extract those words that have exactly one vowel. I do get the correct result with this:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(turns, "\\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*[aeiou][b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*\\b")
[[1]]
[1] "him"  "to"   "stir" "him"  "up"   "now"  "and" 

[[2]]
[1] "when" "when" "i"    "him"  "he"   "on"   "the" 

[[3]]
[1] "yes"  "it"   "for"  "a"    "long"

[[4]]
[1] "it"  "was"
```

However, it feels cumbersome to define a consonant class. Is there a more elegant and more concise way?

Comment: `[^aeiou]`  ? - define a set by excluding the vowels maybe?

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work as it co-extracts neighboring characters such as spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_count` on the words after splitting the 'turns' at the spaces

```
library(stringr)
lapply(strsplit(turns, "\\s+"), function(x) x[str_count(x, '[aeiou]') == 1])
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "him"  "to"   "stir" "him"  "up"   "now"  "and" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "when" "when" "him"  "he"   "on"   "the" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "yes"  "it"   "for"  "a"    "long"

#[[4]]
#[1] "it"  "was"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a PCRE regex with character classes containing double negation:

```r
turns <- c("does him good to stir him up now and again .", 
           "when , when I see him he w's on the settees .",
           "yes it 's been eery for a long time .",
           "blissful timing , indeed it was ")
rx <- "\\b[^[:^alpha:]aeiou]*[aeiou][^[:^alpha:]aeiou]*\\b"
regmatches(turns, gregexpr(rx, turns, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/IPdAnS). The result is as in the question.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SB4FWr/1/). Details:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[^[:^alpha:]aeiou]*` - zero or more chars other than letters and `aeiou` chars
- `[aeiou]` - a vowel
- `[^[:^alpha:]aeiou]*` - zero or more chars other than letters and `aeiou` chars
- `\b` - word boundary.

An equivalent expression:

```r
(?i)\b[^\P{L}aeiou]*[aeiou][^\P{L}aeiou]*\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SB4FWr/2). `\P{L}` matches any char but a letter. `(?i)` is equivalent of `ignore.case=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit` + `nchar` + `gsub`

```
lapply(
  strsplit(turns, "\\s"),
  function(v) v[nchar(gsub("[^aeiou]", "", v)) == 1]
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "him"  "to"   "stir" "him"  "up"   "now"  "and"

[[2]]
[1] "when" "when" "him"  "he"   "on"   "the"

[[3]]
[1] "yes"  "it"   "for"  "a"    "long"

[[4]]
[1] "it"  "was"
```